# React state/child update not behaving as I expected it to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Inside of my react application there are two components

### Navbar

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavLink from './navlink';

class Navbar extends Component {
    state = {
        links: [
            {
                title: "Music",
                active: false
            },
            {
                title: "Home",
                active: false
            },
            {
                title: "Discord",
                active: false
            }
        ]
    }

    updateNavlinks = title => {
        const links = this.state.links
        for (const link in links){
            if (links[link].title != title){
                links[link].active=false;
            }
            else{
                links[link].active=true;
            }
        }
        console.log(links);
        this.setState({links})
    };

    render() { 
        return (
            <div id="Navbar">
                {this.state.links.map(link => <NavLink key={link.title} title={link.title} active={link.active} onClickFunc={this.updateNavlinks}/>) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default Navbar;
```

### Navlink

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class NavLink extends Component {
    state = {
        className: "navlink"+ (this.props.active?" active":"")
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.state.className} onClick={() => this.props.onClickFunc(this.props.title)}>
                {this.props.title}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default NavLink;
```

My intention is to create a navbar where if the user selects a page, that `<Navlink />` has its state changed. Once its state is changed (active=true), I want the classname to change, adding the "active" class and giving it the styles I want.

When `updateNavlinks()` is called, the state in `<Navbar />` is changed, but it doesn't cause a visual change in the associated `<Navlink />`

Where did I go wrong with this? Is there a more simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you're mutating the existing state:

```
updateNavlinks = title => {
    const links = this.state.links
    for (const link in links){
        if (links[link].title != title){
            links[link].active=false;
        }
        else{
            links[link].active=true;
        }
    }
    console.log(links);
    this.setState({links})
};
```

Never mutate state in React - that can make the script behave unpredictably. You need to call `setState` with a *new* object instead, so React knows to re-render:

```
updateNavlinks = titleToMakeActive => {
    this.setState({
        links: this.state.links.map(
            ({ title, active }) => ({ title, active: title === titleToMakeActive })
        )
    });
};
```

Another problem is that you're assigning state in the constructor of the child component in `NavLink`:

```
class NavLink extends Component {
    state = {
        className: "navlink"+ (this.props.active?" active":"")
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.state.className} onClick={() => this.props.onClickFunc(this.props.title)}>
                {this.props.title}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This assigns to the `state` own-property when the component is mounted, but the component doesn't get un-mounted; the instance doesn't change, so `state` doesn't get assigned to again, even when the props change.

To fix it, reference the props inside `render` instead of using state:

```
class NavLink extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"navlink"+ (this.props.active?" active":"")} onClick={() => this.props.onClickFunc(this.props.title)}>
                {this.props.title}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Im confused, I thought that I was creating a new state object when I executed `const links = this.state.links`, modifying that, and then changing the existing state with `this.setState({links})`. that wayI am not mutating the existing state, instead making a copy, mutating that, and then replacing the parent state.

Comment: When you do `const someVarName = someObjReference`, you point `someVarName` to the object, without changing the object, It's like assigning a memory location to `someVarName` - you're not changing anything in memory, you're just copying a new reference to the same object. If you want to *clone* the object, you have to do so explicitly, like with `.map`, spread, or something involving an object literal, etc.

Comment: Upon replacing my code with yours, I'm still not actually seeing any changes.

Comment: You have another logic problem, you're assigning state to the child component in the constructor instead of referencing the props directly in render